# Як правильно назвати масті карт українською?

Tags: значення-слів

Наткнулась на таку картинку
[image]

Здивувало слово жир в якості хрести. Але на моє превелике здивування знайшла його в словнику:

> ЖИР2, у, ч., розм. Те саме, що тре́фа. Голос [Палі Степанівни], як ловкий шулер, перемішав Діагностиці всі його карти, повиймавши з них усе вино та жир, а полишивши саму чирву та дзвінку (Б. Антоненко-Давидович).

Також думала, що трефа - російською, а хреста - українською. Але в словнику знайшла тільки трефу та жир.
Цікавить значення слова жир (в контексті масті), та як взагалі правильно назвати всі масті карт українською?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У Європі історично було 2 найрозповсюджених види [мастей карт](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8)): французькі та німецькі (і менш розповсюджені італійські та іспанські). Французькі масті зараз найрозповсюджені у світі: Trèfle ♣, Pique ♠, Cœur ♥, Carreau ♦.

[Німецькі масті](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_playing_cards) були іншими, це: жолуді [image: жолудь], листя [image: листя], серця [image: серця] та бубонці [image: бубонці]. Вони досі розповсюджені у деяких регіонах Німеччини, Австрії, Швейцарії, Ліхтенштейні та країнах що колись були під німецьким або австрійським впливом, це: Угорщина, Словенія, Словакія, Чехія, Хорватія, частини Польщі, тощо.

Зараз українські масті мають символи від французького набору, а назви — [похідні від німецьких](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82):

> Назви українських мастей є похідними від німецьких: наприклад, чирва — це Rot (червоне); дзвінка (бубна) — від Schellen («бубонці, дзвіночки»); жир (трефа) — від Eicheln, Eckern («жолуді», «букові горішки»), а вина (піка), бо на карті цієї масті малювали зелений листок (листя), найчастіше плюща чи винограду (Weinbaum).

Назву *жир* пояснює словник Грінченка — так колись називалися букові горішки:

> [Жир](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80&scope=ukrq&dicts=12&highlight=on), -ру, м.
>
> 1. Жиръ. То з жиру дуріють; собаки з жиру казяться. Ном. № 10800.
> 2. Кормъ, пропитаніе, добыча (у дикихъ звѣрей). Качки полетіли на жири.
> 3. **Орѣшки изъ дерева букъ**. Каменец. у.
> 4. Трефовая масть (въ картахъ). К. С. 1887. VI. 463. Ум. Жиро́к.

<sup>*Ось стаття на Вікіпедії про [букові горішки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA) — вони дійсно на 40 % складаються з жиру.*</sup>

Однак у словнику СУМ‑11 назва масті *жир* позначена як *розмовне*:

> [ЖИР](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhyr) 2, у, *чол., карт., розм.* Те саме, що [трефа](http://sum.in.ua/s/trefa).

Назва *трефа* не має такої позначки, отже вважається літературною.
Також СУМ‑11 містить назви інших мастей без позначки *розмовне*: *[бубна](http://sum.in.ua/s/bubna)*, *[піка](http://sum.in.ua/s/pika)* або *[вино](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyno)*, *[черва](http://sum.in.ua/s/cherva)* або *[чирва](http://sum.in.ua/s/chyrva)*.

СУМ-11 не має: *жолудь*, *хрест(а)*, *вина*, *дзвінка*.

Натомість СУМ-20 має *[дзвінка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=156759)* з міткою *розмовне*.

Comment: яка гарна відповідь, вона мене тоді минула через великий потік контенту, а зараз мав змогу оцінити.

Answer (score -1):

Карти - одна з найпрадавныших ігр. Вони були придумані ще тоді, коли люди вважали, що світ складається з чотирьох елементів: землі, води, повітря і вогню. Їх симолізували в чотири картові масті: піку, хресту, бубон та черву. Саме так, і не інакше вони були названі. Картам кожної масті були надані умовні позначення їх сили у кількості символічних знаків та повелителів кожної із стихій, наприклад: король пік. Але чому пік, а не саму землю як стихію? А тому, що важко було зобразити землю (грунт), зображали знаряддя, яким її обробляли. Оскільки лопат тоді ще винайдено не було, землю розпушували списами (піками), щосили довбаючи(копаючи) її списами. Отже, картову масть, яку ми сьогодні називаємо виновою зображали у вигляді накінечника списа. Стихію води, як життєдайної рідини, зображали у вигляді хреста не випадково. Адже хрест використовували при освяченні води. Стихію повітря, яке до речі, неможливо було зобразити, зображали у вигляді бубна, інтрумента для відтворення звуку, який поширюється повітрям. А карточну масть саме так і назвали: бубнова. Чому бубон квадратний? Певне вони такими й були. На чотири палки натагували шкуру - от і виходив найпростіший бубен. Круглими їх стали робити пізніше. А ніхто не замислювався чому знак черви називають серцем? По-перше черва занадто мало нагадує серце, а по-друге чому цю масть так називають. Зважте й на те, що у нас ще залишилася стихія вогню. А слово черва праукраїнською означає жаркий, гарячий. То може символ червової масті - не серце, а щось інше? Саме так, це полумʼя свічки перевернуте. Знак вогню. А полумʼя свічки було символом любові так само як і серце символом кохання.

Comment: Добрий день. Чи є якісь підтверждення цієї інформації? Бо виглядає трішки схоже на народну етимологію. Тим більше, що здається, містить явний анахронізм — хіба лопати не з'явилися значно раніше за обряд хрещення води?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Найпростіший бубон був би зі шкіри на трьох палках, але відповідь цікава, хоча не підкріплена джерелами тому не можу плюсанути.

Comment: @Yola, цікаво, що піка англійською буде зокрема _spade_, що означає «лопата».

Comment: @Yola, і в Таро 4 масті справді асоціюють зі стихіями, але там асоціація інша ніж у Віктора, наприклад, земля там бубна, а не піка.